# Progress dialog does not show exactly after show()?

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog, android-progressbar

Found that weird bahaviour of `ProgressDialog`.

I show `ProgressDialog` in `onClickListener` of list before starting new Thread and `dismiss` it inside that Thread but after all work is done:

```
GlobalProgressDialog.show(getActivity());
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //...all other logic
            GlobalProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).start();
```

and that `GlobalProgressDialog` i use to simplify calls:

```
public class GlobalProgressDialog{
private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public static void show(Activity activity){
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();
}

public static void dismiss(){
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Dialog appears but NOT exactly after `show()` being called! I have debugged it and found out that there are 4 standard Android classes are being operated:

1. AdapterView.java
2. AbsListView.java
3. Handler.java
4. Looper.java

And only after `Looper` the `ProgressDialog` is being snown. Is it possible to trick this or fix? Or maybe there's some my fault in code? What could it be?

The **problem** is that delay between item click and `show()` is like 1 sec. So application freezes for 1 sec. And only then dialog appears and all work done takes 1-2 sec, sometimes even 0.5 sec. In such cases its not cool to look at frozen app and flashed for 0.5 sec progress dialog.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Easy solution is use `AsyncTask` instead of `Thread`

Comment: I have already tried AsyncTask. It works the same. Between `preExecute()` and click there's still a gap of time

Answer (score 1):

You're doing too much work on the main thread. `show()` will show the dialog, but it will do so on the main thread. It does not block execution until it is dismissed. So something you're doing in your code after calling `show()` and which you are not showing us, is causing the delay in the appearance of the dialog.

Just to be clear again, this has nothing to do with the `Thread` you're starting and changing it to an `AsyncTask` won't fix it, although it might be a good idea to do that anyway if the pattern fits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a AsyncTask here.

```
   public class DialogAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public DialogAsync(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Perform your logic here
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }


}
```

Usage:

```
DialogAsync globalProgessDialog = new DialogAsync(getActivity());
globalProgessDialog.execute();
```